# How to display data in JOIN, and return null value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How to join two tables and get return **null** value if not available value in another table?

I tried to **join** with many examples that I found, but I've had trouble getting the hoped. Thanks!

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: use LEFT JOIN http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Know your joins: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Please do not paste pictures! Copy your code into your question. Best was a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **LEFT JOIN**:

```
SELECT
    VA.COL_PERSONNEL_NUMBER,
    VA.COL_CLOCK_DATE,
    VA.P10,
    VA.P20,
    VR.NAME,
    VR.UNIT
FROM VIEW_ABSEN VA
LEFT JOIN VIEW_REPORT VR ON VA.COL_PERSONNEL_NUMBER=VR.ID
    AND VR.DATE=VA.COL_CLOCK_DATE
WHERE VA.COL_PERSONNEL_NUMBER LIKE '%521663%'
    AND VA.COL_CLOCK_DATE BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-08-05'
```

Comment: Oh, I am very grateful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a **LEFT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t             -- Specify the table whose value you need to display even when no match is found
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t.id=t2.t_id
```